# How to change the array-key, with a simple summation?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array, whose all keys are numbered by an *integer*:

```
$ArrOne = array (

"-5" => "x",
"-4" => "b",
"-3" => "s",
"-2" => "e",
"-1" => "a",
"0" => "d",
"1" => "k",
"2" => "l",
"3" => "w",
"4" => "y",
"5" => "c"

);
```

And, I have a *integer variable*, like: `$VarKey`.

---

Now, I want to do a simple summation to all keys (of `$ArrOne`), with certain value from: `$VarKey`. The output array is: `$ArrTwo`; for instance:

- If `$VarKey = -1;`, `$ArrTwo` will be:

```
    $ArrTwo = array (

    "-6" => "x",
    "-5" => "b",
    "-4" => "s",
    "-3" => "e",
    "-2" => "a",
    "-1" => "d",
    "0" => "k",
    "1" => "l",
    "2" => "w",
    "3" => "y",
    "4" => "c"

    );
```

- If `$VarKey = 0;`, `$ArrTwo` will not be changed.
- If `$VarKey = +1;`, `$ArrTwo` will be:

```
    $ArrTwo = array (

    "-4" => "x",
    "-3" => "b",
    "-2" => "s",
    "-1" => "e",
    "0" => "a",
    "1" => "d",
    "2" => "k",
    "3" => "l",
    "4" => "w",
    "5" => "y",
    "6" => "c"

    );
```

---

How to solve this problem, with *PHP* language?

Comment: If my question is not clear, please comment below. I will see it; then, I will try to explain more.

Comment: Whats the difference between `If $MyInteger = -1;, $OutArray will not be changed` and `If $MyInteger = -1;, $OutArray will be`?

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov, I am sorry, there is my carelessness. I have updated my question, thank you for your comment.

Comment: The easiest way is to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the input array and build a new array.

Comment: `-5 +(-1)` would give `-6` but not `-4` for `"-4" => "x"`

Comment: @axiac, Thank you for your change, in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the input array and build a new array:

```
$outArray = array();

foreach ($inpArray as $key => $value) {
    $outArray[$key + $MyInteger] = $value;
}

// That's all, folks!
```

Comment: I guess you mean "accepted answer". A flag is a different thing; it is used to bring a question or an answer into the moderators attention because of serious problems: spam, vandalism, an answer that doesn't answer the question etc.